# Raty component in tapestry

Tags: java, jquery, web-frameworks, tapestry

I want to implement raty component and bound it to the existing DB. I have seen raty component of the JQUERY project and seems to be OK, however no demo is presented anywhere, and I can't figure out how does it correctly work.

http://tapestry5-jquery.com/mixins/docsraty

Anyone has deal with this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div t:type="any" t:mixins="jquery/raty" t:ratyValue="4"></div>
```